# How can I get a Windows game to run in windowed mode in Wine (when even explorer /desktop=[resolution] doesn't work)?

Tags: wine, resolution, games

So I bought [Alpha Centauri](http://www.gog.com/game/sid_meiers_alpha_centauri) from GOG and, though I am well aware of the means for forcing applications to go into windowed mode, they just aren't working. This is important because I never played the game before, so I need to be able to switch over to the manual for reference. My issue is simple: can I force Alpha Centauri into a window? If so, how?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you not get a Wine virtual desktop?

Comment: What version of Wine are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.6.2. Yes, muru, that is what I mean.

Comment: I'm guessing Alt+Enter doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

first install [Play on Linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html)

There is a similar question that may help you
[How to start a PlayOnLinux game windowed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290764/how-to-start-a-playonlinux-game-windowed)

If you have any further problems see

[follow this guide](http://www.gog.com/forum/sid_meier_s_alpha_centauri_/playing_smacalien_crossfire_on_ubuntulinux_with_network_support)
[and also this one](http://www.gog.com/forum/sid_meier_s_alpha_centauri_/unofficial_patches/post1)

Comment: This also does not work.

Comment: Changed answer tell me if this works